# OnClick buttons in a listview not recalling selected string

Tags: android

I am working on my first app and I am still learning. I am not a programmer and have a problem that I need some help and guidance with.
My app is a simple custom phone book with a icon, data fields and buttons to call, text, email each contact in a list view.
The number of contacts in my app will be 25-75, but will grow as needed.

The app makes the list view with all the data fields correctly thanks to a tutorial I followed but the buttons to the list view the 
string data from the correct row is not passing.

The problem is happening when I press any of the buttons (dial, text, email) the data recalled is not always correct for the contact selected.

**MainActivity.java** with updated code.

```
package pete.android.study;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvEmail;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvMobile;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvPhone;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView lvPhone = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPhone);

        List<PhoneBook> listPhoneBook = new ArrayList<>();
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar_blue),
                "Name 1", "Manager 1", "000-000-0001", "000-000-1000", "name.1@email.com", "City 1"));
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar_blue),
                "Name 2", "Manager 2", "000-000-0002", "000-000-2000", "name.2@email.com", "City 2"));
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar_red),
                "Name 3", "Manager 3", "000-000-0003", "000-000-3000", "name.3@email.com", "City 3"));
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar_red),
                "Name 4", "Manager 4", "000-000-0004", "000-000-4000", "name.4@email.com", "City 4"));
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar_red),
                "Name 5", "Manager 5", "000-000-0005", "000-000-5000", "name.5@email.com", "City 5"));
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar_green),
                "Name 6", "Manager 6", "000-000-0006", "000-000-6000", "name.6@email.com", "City 6"));
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar_green),
                "Name 7", "Manager 7", "000-000-0007", "000-000-7000", "name.7@email.com", "City 7"));
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar_green),
                "Name 8", "Manager 8", "000-000-0008", "000-000-8000", "name.8@email.com", "City 8"));

        PhoneBookAdapter adapter = new PhoneBookAdapter(this, listPhoneBook);
        lvPhone.setAdapter(adapter);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }

}
```

**PhoneBook.java**

```
package pete.android.study;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class PhoneBook {
    private Bitmap mAvatar;
    private String mName;
    private String mJob;
    private String mPhone;
    private String mMobile;
    private String mEmail;
    private String mRoom;

    public PhoneBook(Bitmap avatar, String name, String job, String phone, String mobile, String email, String room) {
        mAvatar = avatar;
        mName = name;
        mJob = job;
        mPhone = phone;
        mMobile = mobile;
        mEmail = email;
        mRoom = room;

    }

    public void setAvatar(Bitmap avatar) { mAvatar = avatar; }
    public Bitmap getAvatar() {
        return mAvatar;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        mJob = job;
    }
    public String getJob() {
        return mJob;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        mPhone = phone;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return mPhone;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        mMobile = mobile;
    }
    public String getMobile() {
        return mMobile;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        mEmail = email;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return mEmail;
    }

    public void setRoom(String room) { mRoom = room; }
    public String getRoom() {
        return mRoom;
    }

}
```

**PhoneBookAdapter.java** with updated code.

```
package pete.android.study;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvEmail;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvJob;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvMobile;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvMobileButton;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvName;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvOfficeButton;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvPhone;
import static pete.android.study.R.id.tvRoom;


public class PhoneBookAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<PhoneBook> mListPhoneBook;

    public PhoneBookAdapter(Context context, List<PhoneBook> list) {
        mContext = context;
        mListPhoneBook = list;

    }

    private Context context; // added to get startActivity working //

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListPhoneBook.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return mListPhoneBook.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get selected entry
        PhoneBook entry = mListPhoneBook.get(pos);
        ViewHolder holder;

        // inflating list view layout if null
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phonebook_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // Add all items in list //
            holder.ivAvatar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvName);
            holder.tvJob = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvJob);
            holder.tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvPhone);
            holder.tvMobile = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvMobile);
            holder.tvEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvEmail);
            holder.tvRoom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvRoom);
            // Add the buttons //
            holder.tvOfficeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvOfficeButton);
            holder.tvMobileButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMobileButton);
            holder.tvTextButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTextButton);
            holder.tvEmailButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailButton);
            // Set listeners for each button //
            //holder.tvOfficeButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonClickListener);
            //holder.tvMobileButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonClickListener);
            //holder.tvTextButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonClickListener);
            //holder.tvEmailButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonClickListener);
            //

            //

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // set avatar
        holder.ivAvatar.setImageBitmap(entry.getAvatar());

        // set name
        holder.tvName.setText(entry.getName());

        // set job title
        holder.tvJob.setText(entry.getJob());

        // set office phone
        holder.tvPhone.setText(entry.getPhone());

        // set mobile phone
        holder.tvMobile.setText(entry.getMobile());

        // set network
        holder.tvEmail.setText(entry.getEmail());

        // set room
        holder.tvRoom.setText(entry.getRoom());

        // set each button
        holder.tvOfficeButton.setText(entry.getPhone()); //puts the number in the dial button//
        holder.tvMobileButton.setText(entry.getMobile()); //puts the number in the dial button//
        holder.tvTextButton.setText(entry.getPhone()); //puts the number in the dial button//
        holder.tvEmailButton.setText(entry.getEmail()); //puts the number in the dial button//

        holder.tvOfficeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //do your task over here
                Toast.makeText(new MainActivity(), "This is the OFFICE button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                TextView office_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(tvPhone);
                String Office_Phone_Number = office_number.getText().toString();
                //
                // don't change below intent //
                Intent dialOfficeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                //dialOfficeIntent.setData(Uri.parse(office_number)); //working
                dialOfficeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Office_Phone_Number)); //testing
                context.startActivity(dialOfficeIntent);
                //
                Toast.makeText(new MainActivity(), "Press to dial the Office number: "+Office_Phone_Number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        holder.tvMobileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //do your task over here
                Toast.makeText(new MainActivity(), "This is the MOBILE button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                TextView office_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(tvPhone);
                String Office_Phone_Number = office_number.getText().toString();
                //
                // don't change below intent //
                Intent dialOfficeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                //dialOfficeIntent.setData(Uri.parse(office_number)); //working
                dialOfficeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Office_Phone_Number)); //testing
                context.startActivity(dialOfficeIntent);
                //
                Toast.makeText(new MainActivity(), "Press to dial the Office number: "+Office_Phone_Number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        holder.tvTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //do your task over here
                Toast.makeText(new MainActivity(), "This is the TEXT button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                TextView text_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(tvPhone);
                String Text_Mobile_Number = text_number.getText().toString();
                //
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("smsto", Text_Mobile_Number, null));
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Sent from the TechOps App.");
                context.startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });

        holder.tvEmailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //do your task over here
                Toast.makeText(new MainActivity(), "This is the EMAIL button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                TextView email_address = (TextView) view.findViewById(tvEmail);
                String Email_Address = email_address.getText().toString();
                //
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String []{Email_Address});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ADD subject here");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ADD message here");
                context.startActivity(emailIntent);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

        static class ViewHolder {
            private ImageView ivAvatar;
            private TextView tvName;
            private TextView tvJob;
            private TextView tvMobile;
            private TextView tvPhone;
            private TextView tvEmail;
            private TextView tvRoom;
            private Button tvOfficeButton;
            private Button tvMobileButton;
            private Button tvTextButton;
            private Button tvEmailButton;
            }
    //mdm


        //
    }
// END
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/vrFooter"
      android:layout_margin="2dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lvfooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvfooter"
        tools:text="Version:"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:contentDescription="@string/lvfooter"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/vrnumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vrnumber"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/vrdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vrdate"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listPhone"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

**phonebook_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/avatar_image"
        android:scrollbarSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/name_title"
            android:text="@string/name_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvJob"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
            android:contentDescription="@string/position_title"
            android:text="@string/job_title"
            tools:text="Supervisor's Job Title" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tvphonebox">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tvRow1">

                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tvOfficetitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvOfficetitle"
                    tools:text="Office:"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/officephone_title"
                    android:text="@string/officephone_title"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                    tools:text="(000) 000-0000"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tvRow2">

                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tvMobiletitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvMobiletitle"
                    tools:text="Mobile:"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMobile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/mobilephone_title"
                    android:text="@string/mobilephone_title"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    tools:text="(000) 000-0000"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/email_title"
            android:text="@string/email_title"
            tools:text="firstname.lastname@email.com"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tvroombox">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tvBldtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvBldtitle"
                tools:text="Office Location "
                android:paddingRight="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRoom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/room_title"
                android:text="@string/room_title"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:text="ABC####A" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tvcallingbox">

            <Button
                android:text="@string/tvOfficeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvOfficeButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:onClick="onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/tvMobileButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvMobileButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:onClick="onClick" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tvtextingbox">

            <Button
                android:text="@string/tvTextButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvTextButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:onClick="onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/tvEmailButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvEmailButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:onClick="onClick" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="pete.android.study"
       android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1.0">
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_DIAL"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_CALL"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_SEND"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MAIN"/>

     <application android:icon="@drawable/supervisor" android:label="TechOps Supervisors">
         <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                   android:icon="@drawable/supervisor"
                   android:label="Supervisors">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
      App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
         <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

     </application>
 </manifest>
```

How can I get these buttons to work for each contact in my list?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code

```
package pete.android.study;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class PhoneBookAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<PhoneBook> mListPhoneBook;

    public PhoneBookAdapter(Context context, List<PhoneBook> list) {
        mContext = context;
        mListPhoneBook = list;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListPhoneBook.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return mListPhoneBook.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get selected entry
        PhoneBook entry = mListPhoneBook.get(pos);
        final ViewHolder holder;

        // inflating list view layout if null
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phonebook_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // Add all items in list //
            holder.ivAvatar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvName);
            holder.tvJob = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvJob);
            holder.tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvPhone);
            holder.tvMobile = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvMobile);
            holder.tvEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvEmail);
            holder.tvRoom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(tvRoom);


            // Add the buttons //
            holder.tvOfficeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvOfficeButton);
            holder.tvMobileButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMobileButton);
            holder.tvTextButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTextButton);
            holder.tvEmailButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailButton);

            holder.tvOfficeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //do your task over here
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is the OFFICE button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //Better to make tvPhone as EditText instead of TextView
                    makePhoneCall(holder.tvPhone.getText().toString());
                }
            });

            holder.tvMobileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //do your task over here
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is the MOBILE button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    makePhoneCall(holder.tvMobile.getText().toString());
                }
            });

            holder.tvTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //do your task over here
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is the TEXT button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sendTextMessage(holder.tvPhone.getText().toString());
                }
            });

            holder.tvEmailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //do your task over here
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is the EMAIL button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sendEmail(holder.tvEmail.getText().toString());
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // set avatar
        holder.ivAvatar.setImageBitmap(entry.getAvatar());

        // set name
        holder.tvName.setText(entry.getName());

        // set job title
        holder.tvJob.setText(entry.getJob());

        // set office phone
        holder.tvPhone.setText(entry.getPhone());

        // set mobile phone
        holder.tvMobile.setText(entry.getMobile());

        // set network
        holder.tvEmail.setText(entry.getEmail());

        // set room
        holder.tvRoom.setText(entry.getRoom());

        // set each button
        holder.tvOfficeButton.setText(entry.getPhone()); //puts the number in the dial button//
        holder.tvMobileButton.setText(entry.getMobile()); //puts the number in the dial button//
        holder.tvTextButton.setText(entry.getPhone()); //puts the number in the dial button//
        holder.tvEmailButton.setText(entry.getEmail()); //puts the number in the dial button//

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView ivAvatar;
        private TextView tvName;
        private TextView tvJob;
        private TextView tvMobile;
        private TextView tvPhone;
        private TextView tvEmail;
        private TextView tvRoom;
        private Button tvOfficeButton;
        private Button tvMobileButton;
        private Button tvTextButton;
        private Button tvEmailButton;
    }

    private void makePhoneCall(String phoneNumber) {
        Intent dialOfficeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        //dialOfficeIntent.setData(Uri.parse(office_number)); //working
        dialOfficeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber)); //testing
        mContext.startActivity(dialOfficeIntent);
    }

    private void sendTextMessage(String phoneNumber) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("smsto", phoneNumber, null));
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Sent from the TechOps App.");
        mContext.startActivity(sendIntent);
    }

    private void sendEmail(String emailAddress) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailAddress});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ADD subject here");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ADD message here");
        mContext.startActivity(emailIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I did some testing.. Had to add:  TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
  tvName.setText(entry.getName());  and had to change alike for the "set "variables to satisfy gradle.    Working much better but some times I still get the data from the above contact.

Comment: I did some testing and get same result. Trying to add tasks to to the holder.tvPhone.setOnClickListener and now have cannot resolve method findViewById and startActivity. So how do I fix it now?

Comment: show me your code how you did? you have to do convertview.findViewById(). And to start activity you have to use context.startActivity()

Comment: I tried convertview.findViewById() and still not working, but i have used view.context.startActivity() to get that working. Can you explain how the holder works. Onclick is still on MainActivity is that OK?

Comment: I am able to fix convertview.findViewById()  by using view.findViewById()

Comment: So how do I use the holder so that the selected contact provides the right data when I press one of the buttons? All of the code is posted except of only part of phonebook_row.xml. If needed I can send all of the code if needed.

Comment: Why you need this code in MainActivity?
 // mdm Add User Buttons
        Button tvOfficeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvOfficeButton);
        Button tvMobileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvMobileButton);
        Button tvTextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvTextButton);
        Button tvEmailButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvEmailButton);
        //mdm

Comment: You should do this in Adapter. Adapter means set item to the listview . And Viewholder is used to reuse view. don't focus on this now. You have to move your click listener from MainActivity to Adapter.

Comment: I have updated the adapter, but when I press any of the buttons the app crashes. So now what?

Comment: Hmm you can Quit doing Android 

Comment: No, just need guidance on how to proceed. I still don't think the adapter is working, when scrolling the list jumps. Now I don't know where to set the onClickListener, in the adapter. It still in the MainActvity as a onClick. I am unable to run any kind of emulator my PC is to old, and can only test by building apk and loading it. So in list adapter hoe can I reference/pass the correct string to the onClickListener?

Comment: I already show you how to set click listener. Check how I am doing. I

Comment: I got the ViewHolder working, just as you said to do. Now I have to get the buttons to work, now when any pressed the app crashes. More testing...

Comment: Other codes are fine except adapter. I have updated my code. Check it

Comment: Works great! Ajay thank you for the help. So why would it "Better to make tvPhone as EditText instead of TextView work better?" And can this adapter be  applied to a fragment?